# executing a clearcase command through a c program

Tags: c, clearcase

I am trying to execute the following clearcase command through a c program.

```
system("ct pwv");
```

But I'm getting this error. :permission denied.

would you please suggest some solution to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `cleartool`:

```
system("cleartool pwv");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `ct` is an alias for `cleartool`, you can not execute an alias with `system`, as Nicola says use `system("cleartool pwv");`or run an `.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
ct pwv
```

And from C:

```
system("myctpwv.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

`ct` is often defined as an alias (even in Windows: `doskey ct=cleartool $*`).
That means it wouldn't make sense in a C program.

The only other reason is if the process executing your C program has no right to access `cleartool`.
Considering the [`ct pwv` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwv.htm) doesn't list any restriction, that command will work in any path (including one which isn't a snapshot or dynamic view).